# How to override table tr:nth-child for entire table

Tags: html, css

I have the following CSS.  It lets me have a default that table lines alternate background colors, and lets me tell individual rows to not alternate.

Is there any way to do this on a per-table basis, rather than on a per row basis?  IOW, I'd like to just define something at the table level, rather than having to define it for every row.

To put it another way: the property "this table's rows do not alternate" conceptually belongs to the table, not to the individual rows.  Therefore, if possible, I'd like to assign that property to the table, not to each of its rows.

Is that possible?

```
table tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

table tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

table tr.noLine {
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

Thank you,

Comment: At one point or another you will have to tell the rows to use different colours. Unless you mean you just want to alternate the table's background colour

Comment: You mean alternate the background of the tables?

Comment: I want one particular table to have rows that do not alternate their color, and since this is a property of the table, I'd like to specify it at the table level, not the row level.

Comment: @GregDougherty if you want that then you can add a class to that particular table(s) and undo your alternate rows css by overriding them or you can use the css not operator and apply to your current css rules

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
table:not(.nobg) tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

table:not(.nobg) tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

table:not(.nobg) tr.noLine {
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

You would need to add the class `nobg` to the tables that you don't want to alternate colours. The CSS reads for tables that doesn't have class `nobg`, apply the following rules. Check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not for support info.

Comment: That mostly works.  Thank you!  Problem is that I have a table inside of a table, and it's that second (interior) table that I want to "nobg".  And both Firefox and Chrome insist on inflicting the "table:not(.nobg) tr:nth-child(even)" formatting on the even rows of the table.nobg insie a table.

Comment: @GregDougherty Ok that's a slightly different issue. If you see a background colour on the inner table then it is coming from the outer table row. 1) set a bg colour for the nobg class that matches the normal background colour, ie. `#fff` 2) add a class to rows that has inner table and use css to disable the background-color